# Find a basis for the image of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-x_1+x_3,x_1+2x_2+3x_3,2x_1+3x_2+4x_3)$.

Find the matrix representing $T$ in the standard basis.

I have done this and found $A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$.

Next find Ker$T$.

I have done this and found Ker$T=$span{(1,-2,1)}.

Now I need to find a basis of Im$T$.

The solution says I can use any two of the columns from $A$. Could someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the dimensions theorem: for any linear transformation $\;T:V\to W\;,\;\;\dim V=n<\infty\;$ , we have that

$$\dim\ker T+\dim\,\text{Im}\,T=n$$

In your case, it follows that it *must be* $\;\dim\text{ Im}\,T=2\;$ , and since the image of $\;T\;$ is the column space of its matrix, any two of them (check this!) will work.

Answer (score 1):

The columns containing the pivot entries serves as a basis form $Im(T)$

Answer (score 0):

This is because the column vectors of $A$ are the coordinates of $T(e_1)$, $T(e_2$, $T(e_3)$ $(e_1,e_2, e_3)$ being the canonical basis. As the image of $T$ is spanned by the images of the vectors of a basis of $\mathbf R^3$, you just have to find two column vectors which are linearly independent, which can be found by row reduction.

Answer (score 0):

The image of $T$ is exactly the column space of the matrix $A$, and to find a basis of the column space of $A$ you can use the columns (of the original matrix!) that have pivot entries after the reduction.

In your case: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

So the columns with pivots are the first two columns, and a basis for $Im(T)$ could be $\{(-1,-1,2),(0,2,3)\}$.

In this particular case any pair of columns are linearly independent, and since $\operatorname{dim}(Im(T))=2$ any two columns will serve as a basis. However, this is not always the case. For instance, if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & -4 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ the column space will still have dimension 2 but the first two columns are not linearly independent and will not serve as a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(T)$